# How to implement relative path imports in npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, relative-path, npm-package

I have a TS npm package and I want to use a relative path within one of its ts files. This other file is a JSON file and I would be applying its path towards a function almost like reading from the file. How do i apply the path so that it is scoped within that package only and so that if it is applied as a dependency, it would only look within the original package.

I tried this format `../v1/model/model.json` and when I import the package from another, it was scanning within the package that made the import. Assume the path is as follows:

```
|-src
   |-index.js
|-v1
   |-model
       |-model.json
```

Note: This package would be applied client-side so any nodeJS solutions may not apply.

Comment: Do not use relative paths between different node_modules if you can avoid it, it really couples your code tightly to its dependencies. However, if you must reference one of your dependencies via a relative path, go up to the root of your project and start drilling down from `node_modules`